# How to connect to any database in windows 8 metro app?

Tags: javascript, azure, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a problems

1. How to store and retrieve data in any db using metro app

I want that whenever user opens my app and he comes to home page , i fetch some data from server and show him and i also want to save data from my app to server , i searched alot but didn't find any sample of `how to connect windows 8 app with any database , note that i am not talking about any specific server . I am just trying to save and retrieve data and thats it . Please help me and Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx. He shows example with javascript app. On the other hand you can use Windows Azure Mobile Services to connect Azure SQL DB with JavaScript (Example for get Data: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-js/) I hope it helps.